# javascript - access properties of this defined in outer function

Tags: javascript, closures

I've experimented with closures and found unexpected behaviour. Can somebody explain why this code works this way, please?

```
function foo() {
    this.a='hello';
    return {
      aaa:function() {
        return a; // this suprises me, how can be here accessed 'a' ?
      }
  }
}

o=foo();
alert(o.aaa()); // prints 'hello' ! , I expected undefined
```

I don't understand, why I always use `var that=this` phrase,  If it is possible to access function properties from inner functions directly.

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5co6f707/

Comment: `this` doesn't always point to the same object. It depends on how the function is invoked. Writing `var that = this` is a way to capture the original object that `this` references in case that object reference changes later.

Comment: The `this` keyword has nothing to do with closures? If you had used `var a`, it would work.

Answer (score 5):

It displays `'hello'` because you're not in strict mode, so `this` is the global `window` object instead of undefined, and `a` becomes a global variable when you assign a value to `this.a`. Since `a` is a global variable it is accessible everywhere. You could just `alert(a);` at the very end of your script and it would also display `'hello'`: https://jsfiddle.net/5co6f707/1/.

It shouldn't work (and doesn't in strict mode) and it shouldn't be used. If you intend to use `foo` as a constructor then you should use the `new` keyword when you call it (which would break your code, but in a good way).

Comment: Yes, I was too long in node.js, so I forgot the window object phenomenon.

Answer (score -1):

When this code is executed:

```
o=foo();
```

`foo` is executed in global context and so this line:

```
this.a='hello';
```

adds `a` property to the global object - `window`.

When you call your `aaa` function like this:

```
o.aaa()
```

the variable `a` is not defined within the function so it's looked up on up the scope chain and it's found on window:

```
function() {
     return a; // found on window.a
}
```

and so `window.a` is returned.

Comment: guys, I can't understand why this gets repeatedly downvoted? Can you specify a reason at least?